# What is the default timestamp value in php and where we need to change on core?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I checked in my localhost where date_default_timezone_get() function returns 'UTC', I thought it will took the current server's timezone. If not
Where this default setting can be managed in PHP without using date_default_timezone_set() function to set manually?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hit by this issue recently and found the only reliable way was to set the timezone in the php.ini file.  Remember to set it in both the cli php.ini and the apache php.ini.

The logic/rules have changed and evolved over time and this seems the best way to do it now.

Comment: It seems that the timezone set as:
Default timezone  Europe/Berlin on phpinfo();

Comment: have you checked the php ini files?

Answer (score 0):

Open your php.ini file in any plain text editor.

Add this line ( if it is not there already )

```
date.timezone = "US/Central"
```

Go to the php.net manual for getting a list of possible timezones.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Note :- You may have to restart your Apache/WebServer Program with which PHP is running.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on your operating system (OS) and PHP wrapper. For example if you're using Debian in combination with apache2 you can set it in either:

```
/etc/php5/php.ini
```

or

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```